# Why does my code print empty array([]) when I use text files?

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

When I define my array strings in this way:

```java
String[] X = {"X","M","J","Y","A","U","Z"};
String[] Y = {"M","Z","J","A","W","X","U"};
```

my code works and it prints `[M, J, A, U]` which is the longest common subsequence of `X` and `Y` but when I define text files for the string arrays, which have the same input, then my code prints an empty array `[]`. How can I solve this?

```java
    public class LCS   {
    // Function to find LCS of String X[0..m-1] and Y[0..n-1]
    public static String A(String[] x, String[] y, int m, int n, int[][] T)
    {
        // return empty string if we have reached the end of
        // either sequence
        if (m == 0 || n == 0) {
            return new String();
        }
        // if last character of X and Y matches
        if (x[m - 1] == y[n - 1])
        {
            // append current character (X[m-1] or Y[n-1]) to LCS of
            // substring X[0..m-2] and Y[0..n-2]
            return A(x, y, m - 1, n - 1, T) + x[m - 1];
        }

        // else when the last character of X and Y are different

        // if top cell of current cell has more value than the left
        // cell, then drop current character of String X and find LCS
        // of substring X[0..m-2], Y[0..n-1]

        if (T[m - 1][n] > T[m][n - 1]) {
            return A(x, y, m - 1, n, T);
        }
        else {
            // if left cell of current cell has more value than the top
            // cell, then drop current character of String Y and find LCS
            // of substring X[0..m-1], Y[0..n-2]

            return A(x, y, m, n - 1, T);
        }
    }

    // Function to fill lookup table by finding the length of LCS
    // of substring X[0..m-1] and Y[0..n-1]
    public static void LCSLength(String[] x, String[] y, int m, int n, int[][] T)
    {
        // fill the lookup table in bottom-up manner
        for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {

                // if current character of X and Y matches
                if (x[i - 1] == y[j - 1]) {
                    T[i][j] = T[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
                }

                // else if current character of X and Y don't match
                else {
                    T[i][j] = Integer.max(T[i - 1][j], T[i][j - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // main function
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
         String[] X =  read("C:\\Users\\fener\\Desktop\\producerconsumer\\Yeni Metin Belgesi.txt");
         String[] Y = read("C:\\Users\\fener\\Desktop\\producerconsumer\\Yeni Metin Belgesi (2).txt");

        //String[] X = {"X","M","J","Y","A","U","Z"}, Y = {"M","Z","J","A","W","X","U"};
        int m = X.length, n = Y.length;


        // T[i][j] stores the length of LCS of substring
        // X[0..i-1], Y[0..j-1]
        int[][] T = new int[m + 1][n + 1];

        // fill lookup table
        LCSLength(X, Y, m, n, T);

        String[] arr = A(X, Y, m, n, T).split("");
        // find longest common sequence
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.exit(0);
    }
    private static String[] read(String location) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(location));
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((line = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        reader1.close();
        String[] result = new String[lines.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++) {
            result[i] = lines.get(i);
        }
        return result;  
    }
    }
```

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Method names should start with lower case character

Comment: Also you should learn how to use a debugger. It  will help you to find the error

Comment: How are your text files structured?

Comment: @Demetrio each line has one letter

Comment: Your question presents a lot of code and is quite certainly not a minimal example. Please try to shorten the code in your questions to the bare minimum. Often, you’ll find that while preparing a really good questions, you suddenly find the answer yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some pointers:

In Java there is a difference in instantiating a String with the `""` and by using the `new String()` constructor.

For example:

```
// Example 1
String a = "Y";
String b = "Y";
boolean result1 = a == b; // true

// Example 2
String c = new String("Y");
String d = new String("Y");
boolean result2 = c == d; // false
```

This happens because when you create a String using `"Y"`, the actual object is allocated in a separate place in the heap called String Constant Pool. Any subsequent allocation of `"Y"` will return a reference to the same object in the String Constant Pool.

When you use `new String("Y")` you are saying that you want a completely new String object instance to be allocated in the common heap.

The `==` operator compares 2 objects to determine if they reference the same object instance, which in this case will be different as the Example 2 demonstrates.

For the presented code, the necessary changes are:

**In A method**

```
// return empty string if we have reached the end of
// either sequence
if (m == 0 || n == 0) {
    return "";
}
...

// if last character of X and Y matches
if (Objects.equals(x[m - 1], y[n - 1])) {
...
```

**In LCSLength method**

```
// if current character of X and Y matches
if (Objects.equals(x[i - 1], y[j - 1])) {
...
```

Here `java.util.Objects.equals` safely compares with `==` then `equals()`.

By applying these changes the result is:

```
[M, J, A, U]
```

And lastly the `read` method do not need to be changed but could be simplified by using `java.nio` API:

```
private static String[] read(String folder, String filename) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(folder, filename);
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
    return lines.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did everything you stated but this time I get the last element of the first textfile

Comment: Only 3 changes to your code were necessary. Two in A method and one in LCSLength method. See my updated post.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `Object#equals(Object anotherObject)` method to compare strings or, in general, every object.
In your code, you are using `==` operator which will compare the strings references (if they are the same `String` instance) instead of their value.
Your code worked (when using Array initializer) because you initialized the `String` array with literals and two identical literals will be the same instance.
When you read a line in a file with `readLine()`, It creates a new `String` so two lines with the same content will result in two strings with the same value but different instances.
So, when comparing strings, use `equals` and your code will work.
See also: [What is the difference between == and equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java)

Comment: Thank you for the information. It made me understand it